# How to augment expression into select-object in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following code which prints out some properties of each SQL Server related service on a host:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement")|Out-Null;
$mc = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer localhost;
$mc.Services | % {$_|select-object Name,DisplayName,ServiceState}
```

I want to output the result with the HostName appended. I've tried this:

```
$hostName = hostname
$mc.Services | % {$_|select-object Name,DisplayName,ServiceState,@{Name="HostName";Expression={$hostname}}
```

But I just get `>>` displayed. Any ideas on how to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are missing a `}`:

```
$hostName = hostname
$mc.Services | % {$_|select-object Name,DisplayName,ServiceState,@{Name="HostName";Expression={$hostname}}}
```

And you can do it without the `foreach-object`:

```
$mc.Services | select-object Name,DisplayName,ServiceState,@{Name="HostName";Expression={$hostname}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment on `select-object`